# How to manage multiple login Gmail or Facebook to open Same Home Page in Android

Tags: android, email

I am using Facebook and Gmail to log in for Android, and I want that the user is logged in either Facebook or Gmail, user will remain loggedIn unless the logout is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any login Gmail/Facebook and get user data from Gmail/Facebook and save it on device using Shared Preference or Sqlite.
next time when you open your app check the SharedPref/Sqlite contain user data, if it have user data skip login page and navigate to home screen. else stay on login page
when user logged out clear SharedPref/Sqlite data

Comment: I have already done social integration, I just need that to use SharedPref/Sqlite data for passing data. I have just started android

Comment: just refer these link
[for shared Pref](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

and 

[for sqlite](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-login-and-register-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/)